# Generate SOAP Envelope and digital signature

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, digital-signature

So currently we have a model of just writing a SOAP Body and then manually wrapping that into a SOAP Envelope that is done in a script. That then gets passed to an app that makes a request to a webservice. Also, the language the app that would generate the soap would be C++ not C#.

I am looking into building a SOAP Generator that could also generate digital signatures and looking something small and easy to implement as I do not need it to actually make the request as it just hands off the xml to pass another service that sends the request.

I was looking at gSoap http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

But it may be alot of extra stuff just for generating XML, any tips or other libraries that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the XML signature part you could use [Apache Santuario](http://santuario.apache.org/cindex.html).